# How to get the value from a resource dictionary (XAML) in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I'm working on a WPF-application in which the user can change the language (not the current culture!) at runtime.
So i have multiple resource dictionaries of type XAML to which i added texts for making my WPF-app multilingual like that:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Validation_DataAnnotations2.Resources">
    <system:String x:Key="firstname">First name</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="lastname">Last name</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="mainwindowtitle">Validation with DataAnnotations</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="german_language">German</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="english_language">English</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="insert_first_name">The first name has to be inserted</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The WPF-windows and controls are bound by the window resources.
But i'm using DataAnnotations for validation.
My first thought was to get the text to the key "insert_first_name" while the validation in my viewmodel.
So i tried to get it by using this:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.FindName("insert_first_name")
```

But when i use the method FindName, i get null.

And when i try

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.Contains("insert_first_name")
```

i get "true", which means the key exists.

How can i get the value to key?

```
protected void ValidateModel()
{
    validationErrors.Clear();
    ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(personmodel, null, null);
    if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(personmodel, validationContext, validationResults, true))
    {
        foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            string property = validationResult.MemberNames.ElementAt(0);
            if (validationErrors.ContainsKey(property))
            {
                validationErrors[property].Add(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                validationErrors.Add(property, new List<string> { validationResult.ErrorMessage });
                if (validationResult.ErrorMessage == "insert_first_name")
                {
                    var text = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.FindName("insert_first_name");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Raises the ErrorsChanged for all properties explicitly.
    RaiseErrorsChanged("FirstName");
    RaiseErrorsChanged("LastName");
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To look up app-wide resources from code, use Application.Current.Resources to get the app's resource dictionary, as shown here:

```
string insertFirstName = Application.Current.Resources["insert_first_name"];
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)

Comment: Thank You parameter! You are right. I was searching for this the last two hours, reading dozens of articles.

Comment: I’m using an additional ResourceDictionary, and the indexer returns null too. What might be the problem?